# Get words after a certain sign of NSString

Tags: objective-c

I need to get the word that comes after a certain sign, and remove it.

example :

```
NSString *me=@" i am going to make !somthing great" ;
```

I need to remove the word `something`, together with the `!` sign, where ever it will occur in that text.

Is there some method like `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` to not only find the sign ,but identify the word that attached to it  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have reasons not to use regular expressions (or if you are not familiar with them) you can use following

```
NSString *me=@" i am going to make !somthing great" ;
NSRange r1 = [me rangeOfString:@"!"];
if (r1.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSRange r2 = [me rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(r1.location, me.length - r1.location)];
    if (r2.location != NSNotFound) {
        me = [me stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(r1.location, r2.location - r1.location) withString:@""];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to take this approach, I think an NSScanner would work better.

Answer (score 4):

You want a [regular expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In this case, you want one with the pattern `@"!\w*"`. (An NSScanner would also work, but I think a regular expression is more concise in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's code:

```
NSMutableString *mutableMe = [me mutableCopy];
    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"!\\w*" options:0 error:&error];
    [regex replaceMatchesInString:mutableMe options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableMe length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

If you want to find it first than use

```
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:mutableMe options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableMe length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange rangeOfString = [result rangeAtIndex:0];
    [mutableMe replaceCharactersInRange:rangeOfString withString:@""];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following syntax this can help you

NSString *replacedString=[NSString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"!something" withString:@" "];

Comment: I took it that the poster wanted the `!`s to be found and then whatever word is attached to them to be removed; it may or may or may not specifically be `!something`.